# Load scripts via HTTP with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am developing a Chrome Extension, and I have this in my index.html head:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.7.5/beautify-html.js"></script>
```

I am getting this error:

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.7.5/beautify-html.js'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'unsafe-eval'".

Here is my manifest.json config:

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src '*' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src '*';"
```

Does anyone know if there is a possible way to load `<script>'s` which reference a www link? Is there some permissions I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current security policy that you're using only applies to your extension, that is because you cannot use just `*`. Wildcard are allowed but only to construct a URL. If you want to allow  `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com`, you'll have to specify that domain, something like this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com;  object-src 'self';"
```

You can learn more about the `content_security_policy` property from [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy)

Comment: fantastic, I was trying to figure this out for so long, shame that the wildcard `*` does not work